# Speculation about a Future Event

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference between the following two sentences:

```
1. He will be coming tomorrow.
2. He must be coming tomorrow.
```

Answer (score 3):

The sentence with *will* presents his coming as a future certainty. The one with *must* presents it as a logical necessity.

Compare:

*I've just had a letter from Luke. He will be coming tomorrow.*

*I though Luke was coming today, but the last train arrived an hour ago and he wasn't on it. He must be coming tomorrow.*

Answer (score -1):

Your first sentence has the verb in the **future continuous/progressive tense** and means that the subject will be doing an action at a specific point in the future.

The second sentence uses **modal verb must to express certainty**: He will certainly be coming tomorrow.